# Can't understand assignments and environments usage on this recursive function

Tags: python-3.x, function, object, logic

I'm learning about optimization in [Composing Programs](https://composingprograms.com/pages/28-efficiency.html). I have 3 functions. `memo` is for memoization technique, `count` is a wrapper, so every time `fib` is called a counter is activated. `fib` is just an implementation of Fibonacci with recursivity.

```
 def memo(f):
    cache = {}

    def memoized(n):
        if n not in cache:
            cache[n] = f(n)
        return cache[n]

    return memoized


def count(f):
    def counted(*args):
        counted.call_count += 1
        return f(*args)

    counted.call_count = 0
    return counted


def fib(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1)
```

To call the functions, I assing `count(fib)` to `counted_fib`*, so every call is recorded.* And* `fib` *variable is reasigned (now, `fib` is `memo(counted_fib)` not the original function)

```
counted_fib = count(fib)
fib = memo(counted_fib)
```

My problem start when the function `fib` is called (e.g. `fib(19)`) Everything works as it should be, but the recursion inside the original function (`return fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1)`) trigger `fib` as `memo(counted_fib)`.

This is not a problem about something that is not working. I'm just trying to understand why it happens if one thing is declared before another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are confused about is the way that the `fib` name behaves when being reassigned from the original `fib()` function to being a variable calling `memo(counted_fib`, I think [this article](https://realpython.com/python-namespaces-scope/) about python's namespace behavior will help.

Python programs are executed starting from the first statement. But even before that, the global namespace is loaded. So you assign the fib name to `fib()`. But later on, you change that assignment to `memo(counted_fib)`, and that last assignment is the one loaded with the global namespace once the program starts.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

In python, everything is an Object, functions included.

When you declare `def fib` it creates an object call `fib` and this object is `callable`.

This `callable` is calling in self by reference.

When you re-declare `fib = memo(counted_fib)` this move the reference fib to another object. (in this case memo function)

Answer (score 0):

The **count()** function keeps track of each time the **fib** function was called by incrementing a **call_count** variable which can be checked afterwards. Then **memo(counted_fib)** is used to provide caching facilities for the **counted_fib** function. It does so by maintaining a cache object that keeps track of already computed values, thus ensuring that expensive recursive calls to **counted_fib** will not be duplicated when its inputs are called multiple times. Since every time **fib** is called inside **counted_fib**, it gets counted, **memo(countedfib)** ensures that each **counted_fib** call will only run once and all its computations will get cached for future access. Thus, after assigning **counted_fib** it would be possible to make successive calls to **fib** without overwriting its original definition or spend more time in expensive recursive calls.